# Inverse of 256 modulo 47 on $(a^{-1})^n \equiv (a^n)^{-1} \pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, inverse

So I have to find the inverse of 256 modulo 47 by using that:

> $(a^{-1})^n \equiv (a^n)^{-1} \pmod p$

Then we have that $(2^{-1})^8 \equiv (2^8)^{-1} \pmod {47} \implies 24^8 \equiv (2^8)^{-1} \pmod {47}$, but then I feel that the number is getting bigger and it's not right. Where am I messing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a shortcut: $\,16 \cdot 3 = 48\,$, so $\,16^{-1} \equiv 3 \pmod{47}\,$, so $\,256^{-1}\equiv\dots\,$

Comment: Yes, this helps a lot. Thanks!! (answer 9)

Answer (score 1):

A good thing about modulo is that you can keep subtracting 47 to get a smaller number. For example, $24^2=576\equiv 12 \pmod{47}$. Using this you can reduce $24^8$ mod 47.